# Cost of controlled-$U_i$

Tags: gate-synthesis

What is the cost (number of gates) of $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}| i \rangle \langle i|\otimes U_i$ in terms of $N$ and the costs of the unitaries $U_i$? Say the gate set consists of arbitrary one-qubit gates and the CNOT. The unitaries $U_i$ act on an arbitrary number of qubits.

I know, for example, that the Toffoli gate, which is of the above form with $N=4$ and $U_3=X$, can be constructed with $6$ CNOTs.

Comment: Do you wany to be fully polymorphic in the U_i? So you can't tell if there are simplifications from U_i=U_j or U_i=I etc, bc you only have them as black boxes?

Comment: The $U_i$ are black boxes with a given cost. Or is the thing I want not possible in this case?

Comment: So the answer will be a coarse upper bound on the cost. You would need more information about the relations between the U_i if you want that upper bound to be tighter.

Comment: A course upper bound is ok